# [ROS2][bag]not record rotation data

Tags: ros, ros2, rosbag, action

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am following the [tutorial](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Tutorials/Ros2bag/Recording-And-Playing-Back-Data/#ros2-bag-play) for using **ros2 bag**

I used command `ros2 bag record -o test /turtle1/cmd_vel /turtle1/pose` to record the data. 
I draw a cycle by pressing T-> forward arrow-> R-> forward arrow-> E-> forward arrow->  D-> forward arrow->  C-> forward arrow-> V-> forward arrow-> B-> forward arrow-> G -> forward arrow 
It is 8 times move forward + 8 times rotate = 16 counts

However, when I did `ros2 bag play test`, the turtle only moves forward then will throw warning msg:`hit the wall`
So I checked `ros2 bag info test`, it shows:

```
Topic information: Topic: /turtle1/cmd_vel | Type: geometry_msgs/msg/Twist | Count: 8 | Serialization Format: cdr
                 Topic: /turtle1/pose | Type: turtlesim/msg/Pose | Count: 6592 | Serialization Format: cdr
```

It seems it did not record/count the rotate operations.

Any idea why? Or is there any thing I missed?
PS: I am using virtualbox to run the Linux environment for ROS2 in Mac. Could it be the reason?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/340226/%5Bros2%5D%5Bbag%5Dnot-record-rotation-data/) by [lin404](https://answers.ros.org/users/50033/lin404/) on ROS Answers with karma: 60 on 2019-12-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `cmd_vel` message contains both, translation and rotation. But the absolute rotations from the teleop tool use actions (https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Tutorials/Understanding-ROS2-Actions/).

If you try your experiment again with only using arrow keys, it should work.

---

Originally posted by [ct2034](https://answers.ros.org/users/12141/ct2034/) with karma: 862 on 2019-12-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lin404](https://answers.ros.org/users/50033/lin404/) on 2019-12-19**:
I see. `ros2 bag` only records data published on topics, but function using 'T|R|E|D|C|V|B|G' keys is provided by action `rotate_absolute`. Thank you very much!